# Can't set the Class or Module in Storyboard, Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I just updated to Xcode 6.2, now when I create a new ViewController in Storyboard, I can't assign a Class, the Module field is empty. I can't set the Module to the current project, the menu is blank.

The class field doesn't code complete for any class in my project. If I set the class manually I get the error: Unknown class OneViewController in Interface Builder file.

Inspecting the source code of the storyboard file, I can see the that the module is not set for the new view controller. Like I said earlier I can't set this in Storyboard.

I notice also that the default ViewController class is assigned to the default ViewController, and works but, the Module also shows blank for this view.

Comment: Did you quit Xcode and clear the caches? Often that's all it takes. I often have this sort of probably after an update, but clearing all the caches fixes it. See my detailed discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This has been driving me nuts!

Comment: I'm getting frustrated as well. I haven't been able to fix it, either by renaming project folder, clearing caches, or anything. I can't see a damn module so i cant just press that and press enter, there's nothing available in the combo box. Strange thing is that it was working and suddenly stopped working. Source control says nothing changed. Clearly XCode is screwing with me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after updating to 6.2. The way I fixed it was creating a new Cocoa Touch class and copying the code from the one that wasn't working (in your case OneViewController) into that. I deleted the old class and assigned the new one to the View Controller in my storyboard. Error gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you use Xcode 6.2 from App Store, delete it and download version from developer portal. This solves my problem.